# How to merge two consequitve rows in a DataFrame using only specific data from second row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, row

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["2020-03-02 14:04:00", "Repair", "2020-03-02", "14:04:00", "NaN", "NaN"],
    ["2020-03-02 14:07:00", "Repair", "2020-03-02", "14:07:00", "NaN", "NaN"], 
    ["2020-03-02 14:17:00", "Tool change", "2020-03-02", "14:17:00", "NaN", "NaN"],
    ["2020-03-02 14:33:00", "Tool change", "2020-03-02", "14:33:00", "NaN", "NaN"],
    ["2020-03-02 15:04:00", "Repair", "2020-03-02", "15:04:00", "NaN", "NaN"],
    ["2020-03-02 15:07:00", "Repair", "2020-03-02", "15:07:00", "NaN", "NaN"],
    ["2020-03-02 16:04:00", "Repair", "2020-03-02", "16:04:00", "NaN", "NaN"],
    ["2020-03-02 16:07:00", "Repair", "2020-03-02", "16:07:00", "NaN", "NaN"] 
    ], 
    columns=["Index", "Standstillreason", "Date", "Time", "Start", "Stop"]
    )
```

My DataFrame contains pairs of rows that depict the start and stop of a machine downtime. The first row of the pair always show when the downtime started, the second one when it ended.

I would now like to merge each of these pairs, so that one row contains both the start and the end of that downtime:

[image]

I thought about using .groupby, but I think I can't really use it appropriately here, since there might be several different repairs or tool changes on the same day but with the same "Standstillreason".

Which would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please paste your data as text into the question so it can be copied and run.

Comment: Haven't really coded anything useful yet. It's an assignment from my python-class in university and all that works is the first dataframe as you see it above.

Comment: That's fine but why is that preventing you from posting text instead of images of your data?

Comment: ok, I see what you meant. I added the code the best way I could. Apart from the index everything should be the same.